# Retrieve an ISO type date, convert into DateTime and find oldest date from a set of docs

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo

```
{
  id:ObjectID(12fgrh567d8vb9567890578192)
     .
     .
     .
     meta:{
           'date':ISO(1997-07-16T19:20:30.45+01:00)
           }
 }
```

I have this kind of about 500 documents, what I intend to do is define a function in using (pymongo) to retrieve the oldest date from all the documents. I am confused whether I should use the $min function in the ISO format or should I convert it to date time and then go for the $min.

Answer (score 0):

Use following query:

```
db.collectionname.find({}).sort({'meta.date': 1}).limit(1);
```

this will first sort all the documents with the meta date. and will return the oldest one.

Answer (score 0):

`$min` will directly work on IsoDate. No need for conversion.